# Gradient condition implies Hörmander condition

Tags: integral-kernel, multivariable-calculus

We have tempered distribution $K$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ which coincides with a locally integrable function in $\mathbb{R}^n\setminus \{0\}$.  We call the condition
$$\int_{|x|>2|y|}|K(x-y)-K(x)|dx\leq B \hspace{1cm}\forall y\in \mathbb{R}^n$$
for some constant $B$, the Hörmander condition.

> **I want to show that if**
>   $$|\nabla K(x)|\leq \frac{C}{|x|^{n+1}} \hspace{1cm}\forall x\neq 0$$ **then the Hörmander condition holds.**

*For reference, it is from page 92 of the book 'Fourier Analysis' written by Javier.*

**What I have tried is that**, by mean value theorem, for fixed $y$ and for each $x$, there is $t\in [0,1]$ with such that $z(x)=tx+(1-t)y$ and
$$\int_{|x|>2|y|}|K(x-y)-K(x)|dx =\int_{|x|>2|y|} |\nabla K(z(x))||y|dx\leq \int_{|x|>2|y|}\frac{C}{|z(x)|^{n+1}}|y|  dx$$

We are able to say $|z(x)|^{n+1}\geq |tx+(1-t)y|^{n+1}\geq (t|x|-(1-t)|y|)^{n+1}$.

But my problem here is that $t$ is dependent on $x$ so I currently cannot see how I can get further.

Thanks in advance for any helps!

Comment: You can write $K(x-y)-K(x) = -\int_0^1\nabla K(x-ty)\cdot y\,dt$ and then use Fubini.

Comment: @user90189 Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out proving it by using mean value theorem (thanks to @WillieWong). Observe that
\begin{align*}
\int_{|x|>2|y|}|K(x-y)-K(x)|dx &\leq \int_{|x|>2|y|}|\nabla K(tx+(1-t)(x-y))||y| dx\\
&\leq \int_{|x|>2|y|} \frac{C}{|x-(1-t)y|^{n+1}}|y|dx\\
&\leq \int_{|x|>2|y|} \frac{C}{[|x|-(1-t)|y|]^{n+1}}|y|dx&\because |x|>|y|\\
&\leq \int_{|x|>2|y|} \frac{C}{[|x|-|y|]^{n+1}}|y| dx&\because t\in (0,1)\\
&\leq \int_{|x|>2|y|} \frac{C}{[|x|-\frac{|x|}{2}]^{n+1}}|y| dx &\because \frac{|x|}{2}>|y|\\
&\leq \int_{2|y|}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n+1}C}{r^{n+1}}\sigma(n) r^{n-1}|y|dr\\
&=\frac{2^{n+1}C}{2|y|}\sigma(n)|y|\\
&={2^nC\sigma(n)}
\end{align*}

where  $\sigma(n)$ is the measure of unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Comment: First line is missing a $y$: it should be $y \cdot \nabla K$ using the fundamental theorem of calculus. Third line: I absolutely don't see how you just factored out the _vector_ $y$. Instead, why not $$ |x - ty| \geq |x| - t |y| \geq |x| - t |x| / 2 \geq |x|/2 $$ so the third line should read $$ \leq \int_0^1 \int_{|x| > 2|y|} \frac{C|y|}{|x|^{n+1}} dx ~dt $$ and the result trivially follows.

Comment: @WillieWong    If we think of fundamental theorem of calculus, the vector $y$ in the comment should be just a directional unit vector.

I think the third line has a problem. Let me try what you suggested.

Comment: @WillieWong  Thank you!  I made it more clear even though the bound is still depend on $y$ which I did not expect.

Comment: No, $y$ is not a "unit" vector. All the $y$s that appear in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/359262/gradient-condition-implies-h%c3%b6rmander-condition/359354?noredirect=1#comment904433_359262 mean the same thing, and is an arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If you integrate $\int f'(ta) dt $ you get $\frac{1}{a} f(ta)$, not $f(ta)$.

Comment: @WillieWong You are right. I thought wrongly. Thank you!